# Access a JSON member via string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My JSON:

```
json_filter = {"CO": "blah"}
```

I am trying to access the member 'CO' by a string value. However, the result is undefined.

```
var selectedState = $(this).val();
// Selected 'CO'
console.log(json_filter.selectedState);
```

I was thinking eval() might work, but eval() == the devil :) Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
console.log(json_filter[selectedState])
```

Answer (score 1):

`json_filter.selectedState` tries to look up the value with key `"selectedState"` in your object, which doesn't exist. Instead, to look up a value using a variable or expression as your key, use the bracket/subscript notation:

```
json_filter[selectedState]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use brackets

```
json_filter[selectedState]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your JSON is not valid. It should use double quotes:

```
json_filter = {"CO": "blah"}
```

Secondly, to access the member by a string value, you can use this trick:

```
var str = "CO" // or selectedState or whatever
var val = json_filter[str]; // will give you blah
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the bracket notation.

```
json_filter[selectedState];
```