# How to acces a javascript object from another object's value

Tags: javascript, json

```
var jsonObj={"name1":"value1,"name2":"value2"}
var obj="name1";
```

Can i access "value1" like this jsonObj.obj

If cant then how to access the value of name1 without using json object property jsonObj.name1

Comment: Obligatory: that's not a JSON object. It's a JavaScript object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access a JSON member via string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274771/access-a-json-member-via-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use bracket notation to access object properties from strings.

```
var val1 = jsonObj[obj];
```